# PHP: Replace a specific line in csv file

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

I have two `csv files` containing information for a database. What I want to do is read the first file (companies.csv) and replace the line that matches (the first 36 characters) with the same line from the second file (test.csv).

```
$last_file = $this -> fopen_utf8 ("test.csv", "r+");
$comp = $this -> fopen_utf8 ("companies.csv", "r");

while (!feof($comp) && !feof($last_file)){
    while ($line1 = fgetcsv($comp, 0) !== FALSE && $line1 !== NULL){
        while ($line2 = fgetcsv($last_file, 0) !== FALSE && $line2 !== NULL){
            if(substr($line1, 0, 35) == substr($line2, 0, 35)){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking, maybe with `fwrite`, but it doesn't seem right.
Please, any suggestion would be very useful!

Comment: You will need to generate a third (temporary) file and overwrite the first with the new one. Unless the data lines are exactly the same length, any other approach is needlessly complex. You don't have to create a "real" file, you can use `php://temp`, which will do the whole thing in memory if the data is small enough. Also, all those nested `while` loops don't look like a good plan...

Comment: Ditto @DaveRandom Also you are going to have to ensure that you process all of the `Master` file so the new file contains all the original record with any mods.

Comment: this isn't going to work. you read a line from file1, then loop over all lines in file2. when you go read line #2 from file1, you'll be at the end of file2 and have nothing left to compare against.